# Get query execution time via JDBC

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

When activating `\timing` I can see how long a query took to execute in postgres. Is it possible to access this information via the postgres JDBC driver? (N.b.: I searched for it and could not find any possibility)

Comment: No, that's not possible. The `\timing` option is implemented in the `psql` client. You have to do the same inside your application or enable query logging, so that the queries are logged with their runtime in the Postgres logfile: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#GUC-LOG-DURATION

Comment: Thank you for this information. If you feel that it is appropriate you may post it as an answer.